# iOS Parse Stripe Integration

Tags: ios, api, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I'm fairly new to programming and I created an app to charge customers and would like to store their CC information and charge it at a later time. I've been going through all the tutorials and documentation and I am unable to follow how I can integrate this into my app. Do I need to know other technical skills such as Rest API, Curl, Ruby, etc to get this set up? All the guides and documentation is pointing to that direction. I don't really understand what GET/POST is for and how that fits into iOS Objective-C programming.

Any guidance on how to set this up would be tremendously appreciated. I've been stuck on this for some time now.

Comment: Feel free to visit my tutorial! If you have any issues just make one in the git issues https://github.com/jsetting32/Stripe-Connect-Parse. The cloud functions I implemented go into thorough description of how to do this

Answer (score 9):

Parse's stripe API is not as complete as it could and should be. There are many features it does not include natively, but can be accomplished VIA an HTTP Request. I had to learn a little bit of Javascript, and HTTP request to get many features working. Of course your first instinct should tell you do NOT store a CC number on any device ever! Anytime you have a user input a CC number, immediately get a token and then that is all you will need to use.

Luckily stripe gives you the ability to save customers, and attached CC to customers, and then charge that customer in the future without getting the CC number again. Parse's api does not handle adding a CC to a customer so I added the feature myself.

So Step 1 and 2 Generate a Customer using Parse's API, and generate a Token from the CC information they enter again using Parse's API. If you need help with this, and the cloud code required let me know.

Step 3 Add a CC to a customer. I'm using a custom Customer object, but the main thing you really need is the stripe customerId which is customer.identifier in my code, and tokenID from your CC which in my case is token.tokenId. The response back will be a JSON string with the card information, I turn this into a Dictionary, and then create a STPCard from the dictionary. Also I show how to remove a card from a customer.

iOS Code:

```
    +(void)addToken:(STPToken *)token toCustomerId:(NSString *)customerId completionHandler:(PFIdResultBlock)block
{
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"stripeUpdateCustomer" withParameters:@{@"customerId":customerId,@"data":@{@"card":token.tokenId}} block:block];
}

+ (void)removeCard:(STPCard *)card FromCustomer:(ELCustomer *)customer completion:(STPCardDeletionBlock)handler
{
    if (!customer ||!customer.identifier || !card || !card.identifier || !handler) [NSException raise:@"RequiredParameter" format:@"Required Parameter Missing for deleting card from customer"];

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"stripeDeleteCardFromCustomer" withParameters:@{@"cardId":card.identifier,@"customerId":customer.identifier} block:^(id object, NSError *error)
    {
            NSDictionary *dict = nil;
            NSError *jsonError = nil;

            if (object && [object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && !error) {
                dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[object dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];
            }
            if (!jsonError && dict) {
                handler(dict[@"id"],[dict[@"deleted"] boolValue],error);
            }
            else if(jsonError) handler(nil,NO,jsonError);
            else handler(nil,NO,error);
    }];
}
```

Cloud Code Required:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("stripeUpdateCustomer", function(request, response) 
{
        Stripe.Customers.update
    (
        request.params["customerId"],
        request.params["data"],
        {
            success:function(results)
            {
                console.log(results["id"]);
                response.success(results);
            },
            error:function(error)
            {
                response.error("Error:" +error); 
            }
        }
    );
});

Parse.Cloud.define("stripeDeleteCardFromCustomer", function(request, response) 
{
        Stripe.initialize(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                method:"DELETE",
                //STRIPE_SECRET_KEY will be your stripe secrect key obviously, this is different from the public key that you will use in your iOS/Android side.
                // STRIPE_API_BASE_URL = 'api.stripe.com/v1'
                url: "https://" + STRIPE_SECRET_KEY + ':@' + STRIPE_API_BASE_URL + "/customers/" + request.params.customerId + "/cards/" + request.params.cardId,
                success: function(httpResponse) {
                response.success(httpResponse.text);
                },
                error: function(httpResponse) {
                response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
                }
        });
});
```

iOS Code for applying a charge to a customer or token notice the required parameters in the dictionary are an amount in cents not dollars, a currency, and then either a customer or a tokenId. Note a customer can have many credit cards, but one of them is the active credit card. The active card is the card that will be charged when you charge a customer:

```
//Will attempt to charge customer, if no customer exists, or it fails to charge the custoemr it will attempt to charge a card token directly;
//*********Warning: This is the final step it will APPLY A CHARGE TO THE ACCOUNT.***************

-(void)processChargeThroughStripeWithCompletionHandler:(STPChargeCompletionHandler)handler
{
    if (![self validForCardProcessing] && ![self validForCustomerProcessing]) {
        handler(nil,[NSError errorWithDomain:MY_ERROR_DOMAIN code:elErrorCodeNoCustomerOrTokenID userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionary]]);
        return;
    }
    [self processChargeThroughStripeUsingCustomerWithCompletionHandler:^(STPCharge *charge, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!error) handler(charge,error);
        else{
            [self processChargeThroughStripeUsingCardWithCompletionHandler:^(STPCharge *charge, NSError *error) {
                handler(charge, error);
            }];
        }
    }];
}

//Process payment using a customer to their active card. No token is required if customer exists with a card on record.
//*********Warning: This is the final step it will APPLY A CHARGE TO THE ACCOUNT.***************

-(void)processChargeThroughStripeUsingCustomerWithCompletionHandler:(STPChargeCompletionHandler)handler
{
    if (!self.validForCustomerProcessing)
    {
        handler(self,[NSError errorWithDomain:MY_ERROR_DOMAIN code:elErrorCodeNoCustomerID userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionary]]);
        return;
    }
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"chargeToken" withParameters:[STPCharge dictionaryFromSTPChargeForProccessingUsingCustomer:self] block:^(id object, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            [self initSelfWithDictionary:object];
            NSLog(@"object:%@",object);
        }
        handler(self,error);
    }];
}

//Process payment using a token that is attached to the charge, when complete self will be updated with the new charge information
//*********Warning: This is the final step it will APPLY A CHARGE TO THE ACCOUNT.***************

-(void)processChargeThroughStripeUsingCardWithCompletionHandler:(STPChargeCompletionHandler)handler
{
    if (!self.validForCardProcessing)
    {
        handler(self,[NSError errorWithDomain:MY_ERROR_DOMAIN code:elErrorCodeNoTokenID userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionary]]);
        return;
    }
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"chargeToken" withParameters:[STPCharge dictionaryFromSTPChargeForProccessingUsingCard:self] block:^(id object, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             [self initSelfWithDictionary:object];
         }
         handler(self,error);
     }];
}
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromSTPChargeForProccessingUsingCard:(STPCharge *)charge
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    dictionary[@"amount"] = charge.amountInCents;
    dictionary[@"currency"] = charge.currency;
    dictionary[@"card"] = charge.token.tokenId;
    return dictionary;
}
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromSTPChargeForProccessingUsingCustomer:(STPCharge *)charge
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    dictionary[@"amount"] = charge.amountInCents;
    dictionary[@"currency"] = charge.currency;
    dictionary[@"customer"] = charge.customer.identifier;
    return dictionary;
}
```

Cloud code for charging a customer/token:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("chargeToken",function(request,response)
{
    Stripe.initialize(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
    Stripe.Charges.create
    (
        request.params,
        {
            success:function(results)
            {
                response.success(results);
            },
            error:function(error)
            {
                response.error("Error:" +error); 
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the support. I am not storing any CC on my DB or the device bc I know there are compliance issues w/ that. What I'll do is learn GET and POST... What language could I learn that? Ruby? Also do I need to learn XML or Node at all? Not really clear on what that is. I hope you all forgive me for the lack of knowledge. I've been out of the tech scene for over 10 years and I've self taught objecticeC and I'm trying to puzzle all the pieces together! Thanks.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, taught myself objective c, and have to dig into other languages since I'm trying to work with some backends. The Parse cloud code is javascript which you may have already dug into.  I like parse because it makes it easy to jump right in without an in depth knowledge of all of the backend languages. As far as get/post you can do that from objective c if you want. I'm using parse cloud code to execute my HTTP Post's because I need to use my secret key. Never use your secret key on the end user device. Passing it through the parse server is what keeps the transaction secure.

Comment: hi, thanks for the feedback. So what you're saying is cloud code is javascript and it's cloud computation? It would execute code and return results to the device? I don't know any Javascript so that might be the reason why I'm not following the cloud code portion you provided. Is there a specific part of javascript you recommend I pick up to implement this in my app? also do you know what I put in the URL link provided from Stripe API documentation? what is this URL for? It it supposed to be pointing to a stripe URL? initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com"]

Comment: Cloud code is implemented on parse.com. The iOS app can communicate with parse.com, and execute javascript code that you write and host on parse.com. You can also pass and receive variables easily using a dictionary. NOTE: NEVER execute this url on the end user device, you would share you secret stripe key, and anyone could have the ability to everything in your stripe account. The resulting HTTPRequest url in the cloud code would look something like this(copy url as it gets cut off):https://sk_test_example_stripe_secretKey@api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_example_cust/cards

Comment: You would also need a body which would look like this:"card=tok_example_token_id"

Comment: thanks for the feedback. It's been a few weeks and I'm still working on this piece of my iOS app. If you don't mind, do you have GitHub project you can share that you have this set up? thx.

Comment: Why not use `Stripe.Customers.create/update/destroy/etc...` instead of the HTTP requests? https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Stripe.Customers.html

Comment: I do use parse's modules when they work. There are certain stripe features that parse's API doesn't accomplish and that is what I use http request for. In this example adding a cc to a stripe customer is not possible using parse's module right now.

Comment: @hybrdthry911 the `data` parameter of the methods in the Parse Stripe module can take a `card` parameter. From the Stripe.Customers.Update method: "{Object} data - The parameters as defined by Stripe. If the 'card' parameter is used it should contain a card token, not an actual credit card." Have you tried this? I am actually curious, haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Parse's module failed to attach a card to a customer for whatever reason when I tried. It's been a while, this may have been corrected though.

Comment: You haven't tried yourself, yet you already downvoted me? If you update a customer with a card it now works and I will update my answer for adding a card to customer, but there is no method for deleting a card using Parse API so you still need to use an http request for that anyway.

Comment: @hybrdthry911 I actually didn't mean to downvote you, but couldn't take it away once I noticed (24 hr had passed). Anyways, I tried using the Parse.Customers.create with the data parameter and successfully added a card, as you did. For deleting a card you are correct. Normally a blank parameter unsets a value but that's not allowed for the 'card' parameter.

Comment: Great answer btw, wish you'd given me something like this!

Comment: Vishal do you know if we can modify that code and implement additions? I know they went open source with a lot of stuff but not sure if/how much we can modify the JavaScript modules.

Comment: @hybrdthry911 this answer is fantastic. Was wondering if you know how Stripe Connect (user to user payments) works for iOS? How would the Cloud Code work with that?

Comment: @lukesIvi I would ensure you are prepared for the imminent parse shutdown which will occur in 1 year. With that said I have posted elsewhere about my one size fits all cloud code that can execute any stripe function needed. It's quick to implement and allows you to follow closely to stripe documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I'm aware. Can you send me the one size fits all code?

Comment: Stripe connect gets into oauth I believe so it may not be able to handle it but you could build something similar if it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will keep you updated :)! @hybrdthry911

Answer (score 1):

How are you storing their CC information to charge it at a later time? Before proceeding, you need to know if it is PCI compliant or not. At most, the only things you should be looking to store is the expiration date, last 4 digits, and an associated record object that Parse Stripe gives you that corresponds to that CC. Do not try to store the full CC.

As to your other questions:

Generally you need to know a web language to do something like this. Here is an example of a possible stack that I've seen in a situation like this:

iOS App -> sends request to Server (rails, python, php, etc) -> Will send request to 3rd party site

3rd party site response -> Server -> iOS app.

The point of the server is to intercept the call from the mobile App to Parse, and the response from Parse back to the mobile app. The reason for this is so you can have a "master" db of the transactions/states and can recover if the app is ever reinstalled on the user's phone. It also will let you store an identifier that points to the user's CC on parse stripe (I'm assuming).

You should really understand GET/POST as they are becoming a very basic feature of any iOS app. They are simply how you get/insert records from a server. Considering almost all of the popular apps have some kind of network connectivity embedded in them, it really is a core part of iOS programming IMO.